# Calculus II Volume of Revolution

Tags: calculus, volume

Consider the closed region bounded by 
$y = 5e^{−x}$, $y = 5$, and $ x= 4$.

In each case, write an integral giving the volume of the solid.

(a)rotate the region around the x-axis.

Can anyone give me some help on this problem? The limits of integration are from 0 to 4 but I am having trouble determining the radius. To me, it seems that the radius is $5e^{-x}$ but that is incorrect. Can someone lead me in the right direction to finding the correct radius?

Comment: Incidentally, your first calculation would be the volume of material *removed* from a cylinder of radius $5$ and length $4$ to obtain the given solid. That is, you calculated the "negative space" inside the solid. So you can still use this value to find the required volume:
$$V_\text{solid} = V_\text{cylinder} - V_\text{negative space}$$
Compare this to the calculation in the answer I gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a cross-section perpendicular to the $x$-axis, you will get a ring with an outer radius ($r_1=5$) and an inner radius ($r_2=5e^{-x}$). The area of that ring is $$A(x) = \pi r_1^2 - \pi r_2^2 = \pi 5^2 - \pi (5e^{-x})^2.$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound of the integral should be $5$ because the area is bounded by $y = 5$.

The lower bound of the integral should be $5e^{-4}$ because the area is bounded by $x = 4$.

The height of our shell should be $4 - (-ln(\frac{y}{5}))$ (you can find it out if you plot the graph of $y = 5e^{-x}$ and find the bounded area.)

Shell Method:
$$\int_{5e^{-4}}^{5}2\pi y(4+ln(\frac{y}{5}))dy$$